# Unable to validate the 'id_token', when specifying scope with OpenIdConnect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, openid-connect

I have an app that is written on the top of an old ASP.NET MVC 5 framework using `C#`. I want to enable OpenIdConnect authentication to allow my users to authenticate using a private OpenId server.

I was able to add the OpenId external provider using [Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect/) project. Currently, I am using [Code Flow](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#CodeFlowAuth) to authentication users. Here is how configured the OpenId authentication provider

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions()
{
    Authority = "openid-server-domain.com",
    RedeemCode = true,
    SaveTokens = true,
    ResponseType = "code",
    ClientId = "***",
    ClientSecret = "***",
    RedirectUri = "https://localhost:55555/connect/redirect",
    Scope = "profile",
    PostLogoutRedirectUri = "/disconnect/sign-out"
});
```

When I add `Scope = "profile",` the app throws an exception after the user logs in. The exception states

> Unable to validate the 'id_token', no suitable ISecurityTokenValidator was found for: ''."

Removing the `Scope = "profile",` works without exceptions, but I need to add the scope so that the server returns user's profile info.

How can I fix this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I needed to include `openid` as part of the profile to work.

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions()
{
    Authority = "openid-server-domain.com",
    RedeemCode = true,
    SaveTokens = true,
    ResponseType = "code",
    ClientId = "***",
    ClientSecret = "***",
    RedirectUri = "https://localhost:55555/connect/redirect",
    Scope = "openid profile",
    PostLogoutRedirectUri = "/disconnect/sign-out"
});
```